# How to print out the specific item of an array using .addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, arrays, addeventlistener

I'm creating a sort of tic tac toe game. I have a grid mapped out in .html, and I'm trying to get the each box to say "You clicked 'box location'" when pressed.

The element id's are labeled from 0-8.

```
let grid =['topLeft','topMid','topRight','midLeft','midMid','midRight','botLeft','botMid','botRight'];

var clickFunction = function() {

    console.log("You Clicked " + grid[i]);  
};

for(i=0; i<grid.length; i++) {
    grid[i] = document.getElementById(i);
    grid[i].addEventListener("click", clickFunction);
}
```

It currently prints out "You clicked undefined". How do I get it to print "You clicked topLeft" for example?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the index to `clickFunction`

```
var clickFunction = function(i) {

console.log("You Clicked " + grid[i]);  
};

for(i=0; i<grid.length; i++) {
  grid[i] = document.getElementById(i);
  grid[i].addEventListener("click", () => clickFunction(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first: change this line:

```
grid[i] = document.getElementById(i);
```

to:

```
ele = document.getElementById(grid[i]);
```

Because you need to save the i value for each element in the handler you can change your handler to:

```
var clickFunction = function(i) {
    return function(e) {
       console.log("You Clicked " + grid[i]);
    }
};
```

In this way, when you attach the handler (... clickFunction(i)) you save the value of variable.

```js
let grid =['topLeft','topMid','topRight','midLeft','midMid','midRight','botLeft','botMid','botRight'];

var clickFunction = function(i) {
    return function(e) {

        console.log("You Clicked " + grid[i]);
    }
};

for(i=0; i<grid.length; i++) {
    ele = document.getElementById(grid[i]);
    ele.addEventListener("click", clickFunction(i));
}
```

```html
<button id="topLeft">topLeft</button>
<button id="topMid">topMid</button>
<button id="topRight">topRight</button>
<button id="midLeft">midLeft</button>
<button id="midMid">midMid</button>
<button id="midRight">midRight</button>
<button id="botLeft">botLeft</button>
<button id="botMid">botMid</button>
<button id="botRight">botRight</button>
```